# Invalid property value on background image and image is not showing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add image through below mentioned code but its not adding.

```
background: linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5),url('images/test.jpg'));
```

Comment: still same error is occured

Comment: `linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) ,url('images/test.jpg')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this it should work fine :

```css
background: url("Dr.jpg") no-repeat left top, linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531)
```

*Image_url:set your own image url there

*you can change the colors on your own
*IF WE DON't use no-repeat the image will be repeated

Comment: grdient is working but the image url is not working

Comment: it should be inside a div to work also the image width and height should be inferieur au div height and width try it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you are misplacing parenthatheses , simply do :

```
background: linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('images/test.jpg');
```